# What is wrong in this declaration of multidimensional array?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
dp = [[False]*n]*n
for i in range(n):
    dp[i][i] = True
```

But it will set all elements to true. For example, for n=2, I will get [[True, True], [True, True]] where I am expecting [[True, False], [False, True]]

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: @Makoto: No, there's a single loop over the diagonal. The problem is an aliasing issue.

Comment: Ah.  I read it took quickly.  I'll just sheepishly delete my comment...

Comment: You didn't create a multidimensional array.  Your outer list contains `n` references to the *same* inner list, not `n` different lists.